# Comparison help through Instr Function

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I want to convert `int` into `string` in VB6 and parse that `string` into `Instr` function, but I am unable to do that, here is my code:

```
'.WebElement("total_Count").GetROProperty("innertext")=1 - 10 de 31 candidatos 
'This is the value in innertext, and i want to compare the 31

totalCount=31
CStr (totalCount)
        If InStr(totalCount,.WebElement("total_Count").GetROProperty("innertext"))>0Then
                MsgBox "Found"
                Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"DBVerification","TotalCount Verified From DB"
                Else
                MsgBox "Not Found"
                Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"DBVerification","TotalCount Not Verified From DB"
        End If
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you please explain more what you want to do. Do you want to check if the string from `.WebElement("total_count")` contains the text `31`? This is inconsistent with your comment `10 de 31 candidatos`

Comment: FYI QTP tests are VBScript and not VB6

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons on VB6 are case sensitive unless `Option Compare Text` is used at top of the module/form/class; in this particular case it wouldn't matter though. Also, `CStr(totalCount)` is not assigning to anything is not changing TotalCount into a string; it returns a string.

```
totalCount=31

If InStr(lcase(CStr(totalCount)),lcase(.WebElement("total_Count").GetROProperty("innertext")))>0 Then
   MsgBox "Found"
   Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"DBVerification","TotalCount Verified From DB"
Else
   MsgBox "Not Found"
   Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"DBVerification","TotalCount Not Verified From DB"
End If
```

Comment: The questioner did flag it under VB6, but that is incorrect. It is VBScript. In VBScript you don't have to `lcase` numbers to transform them into... numbers and I doubt you have to do that in VB6 too.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not comparing them as numbers, the way you are doing it, if totalcount=31 and innertext contains 1 you will get True which is surely not what you want.

Comment: Peeking in his comment, the application returns something like "results 1 to 10 of 31 total". He wants to see is 31 is in the string to see if the total count is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Swap the arguments of the Instr() function:

`InStr(.WebElement("total_Count").GetROProperty("innertext"), totalCount)>0`

*Now* you are looking if 31 is inside your innertext. You don't have to use `cStr()`, `lCase()` or other stuff, VBScript will do that for you.

Edit: What you really want to make it work right is a regular expression of course:

```
Dim regEx, matches, actualTotal
set regEx = new RegExp
regEx.Global = True
regEx.pattern = "\d+ - \d+ de (\d+) candidatos"
Set matches = regEx.Execute(Value)
actualTotal = matches(0).submatches(0)
```

Now you can compare actualTotal with the expected total, without the bothering if the number is in the rest of the string.
For example:
"31 - 40 de 42 candidatos" will result in a false positive. Using a RegExp you prevent that behaviour.